# How to get values OpenGL calculated between given height levels?

Tags: c++, opengl, texture-mapping

I need the coordinates that OpenGL calculate between different height levels linearly.

I have a high level map in the size 64 x 64 px and a texture that I present corresponding to the height map. This representation is substantially greater than 64 x 64 px, so OpenGL calculated intermediate values (probably linear), so that no steps are formed in the 3D space.

I could use this intermediate values to use the marching squares algorithm optimally, without to perform a linear interpolation by myself, as the graphics card has already done this to adjust the texture to the heights.

Is it possible to get the z coordinate using a function stating the x and y coordinates?

Answer (score 0):

OpenGL just draws points, lines and triangles. There's no such thing as a "scene" or "models" in OpenGL. Interpolation happens merely on the primitive (= lines or triangles) level. Inside the shader stages lots of things can happen, but as far as OpenGL is concerned it's totally agnostic about what the shader programs do. You can read back the computations of vertex shaders using transform feedback. The output of fragment shaders are images (which you can read with glReadPixels) and compute shaders operate directly on memory.

> Is it possible to get the z coordinate using a function stating the x and y coordinates?

Certainly, if you're able to define in program how the Z coordinate depends on the x,y pair and the input data (= height map). So you as a programmer have to program this and thus can also program how to read it back. OpenGL is completely agnostic about this but gives you all the low level operations required to implement this.

OpenGL is not some kind of "magic" geometry processor.